# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и": "Бабочки проснулись(,) и стрекозы проснулись"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и": *Бабочки проснулись(,) и стрекозы проснулись*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно нужна. Если предложение оставить в таком виде (с повторяющимся сказуемым), оно будет сложносочинённым: два простых, разделённых союзом И.

Answer (score 2):

**Бабочки и стрекозы наконец заинтересовали и меня.**

Я не стала сразу отвечать на этот вопрос, поэтому что неясен был контекст, хотя он и сейчас неясен. Я даже не поняла, к чему относится знак вопроса (а вдруг к самому предложению).

Но в принципе здесь возможны **две ситуации**: (1) простое перечисление  событий и (2) их взаимосвязь.

1) ***Бабочки проснулись, и стрекозы проснулись.***

Это перечисление, и повтор глагола здесь **не речевая избыточность**,  он имеет усилительное значение (**все** проснулись). В то же время стилистику предложения окончательно можно проверить при наличии контекста.

2) ***Бабочки проснулись — и стрекозы проснулись*** (ССП). Этот вариант сомнителен: тире в ССП неосновной знак, временные и условные значения он не выражает http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

***Бабочки проснулись — стрекозы проснулись тоже*** (БСП)

Смысл такой: если одни проснулись, значит, другие проснулись тоже.

**И вывод:** в предложенной редакции верен единственный вариант с запятой: ***Бабочки проснулись, и стрекозы проснулись.***

Answer (score 0):

Как верно сказал Артём, запятая тут нужна. Другой вопрос — надо ли вообще так строить предложение. При оценивании работы такое сочетание будет считаться повторением, или тавтологией. Чтобы этого избежать, предлагаю переделать предложение:

**Бабочки и стрекозы проснулись.**

Единственным исключением является постановка логического ударения и, соответственно, тире:

**Бабочки проснулись — и стрекозы проснулись.**

Или другой вариант:

**Бабочки проснулись — стрекозы тоже.**

Причём, следует отметить, логическое ударение, хоть и падает на одну часть (правда, видоизмененную, что и обусловливает изменение смысла), несёт различный смысл в обоих случаях.

Comment: Зачем запятая после "причём"?

Comment: При редактировании я уже отметил, что запятая относиться не к "причём", а к вводной конструкции. Вариант, предложенный тобой, также уместен, но имеет несколько иной смысл.

Comment: Не заметил комментария к правке. Согласен тогда с этой запятой. И всё же я бы убрал запятую перед "хоть" и добавил бы перед "несёт" "но" или "однако". А то так плохо читается фраза.

Comment: Если хотите, могу изменить на "хотя")

Comment: С "хотя", imho, будет даже хуже. По-моему, союза не хватает. Если переставить местами — "хоть логическое ударение и падает", — запятая не нужна. Так почему она так может возникнуть?

Comment: "Хотя" — союз, необходимый для образования придаточного предложения со значением уступки. Здесь я главным предложением сделал часть с "несёт".

Comment: Хорошо, можно я задам вопрос об этом?

Comment: Конечно, задавайте.

Comment: Почитайте же наконец, что такое тавтология и чем она отличается, скажем, от лексического повтора.

Comment: @Бот, никакой тавтологии здесь нет.

Comment: О тавтологии и повторе: https://studfiles.net/preview/1608875/page:15/   Если коротко, то это выглядит так. Существует понятие речевой избыточности: тавтология. плеоназм, повтор. Тавтология - однокоренные слова, в том числе иноязычные  (рассказать рассказ, необычный феномен), плеоназм -  близкие по смыслу слова (глубокий мрак,  предчувствовать заранее), повтор -  одни и те же слова (получены результаты, результаты показали).

Comment: Разве это кардинально меняет смысл? На мой взгляд, употребление таких сочетаний всё же не является желательным.

Comment: Я просто уточняю терминологию, чтобы по ней не было вопросов. Здесь повтор, не тавтология. А предложение действительно может иметь разный смысл. Вы правильно  поняли это, но раскрыли тему недостаточно полно и точно, к тому же ошиблись в терминах. Смысловые различия никто не оценил и не заметил, а критиковали совсем другое.

Comment: Тему я решил не раскрывать из-за отсутствия прямой связи с вопросом. А в терминах я действительно ошибся.

Comment: Кстати, насчёт "— и стрекозы проснулись". Здесь я для себя сделал акцент на том, что одно событие следует из другого. Во втором же случае я решил подчеркнуть важность пробуждения стрекоз.