# Правильно ли составлено предложение? (2)

Tags: синтаксис, запятые, союзы

Речь о фразе из ответа Бота на [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452232/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C/452236?noredirect=1#comment462219_452236) вопрос:

> *Причём, следует отметить, логическое ударение, хоть и падает на одну часть (правда, видоизмененную, что и обусловливает изменение смысла), несёт различный смысл в обоих случаях.*

Мы с ним не сошлись во мнениях. Он считает, что фраза правильно составлена, а я считаю, что перед ***хоть*** запятая не нужна, что в придаточное, о котором говорит Бот, входят слова *"логическое ударение",* поскольку при перестановке *("хоть логическое ударение и падает")* запятой нет, стало быть, непонятно, что меняется при возвращении к исходному варианту. И ещё мне кажется, что перед ***несёт*** очень не хватает союза ***но*** (конструкция "хоть и... но") или ***однако***.

Comment: Артем, Вы всё правильно считаете, и очень хорошо, что проверяете текст ответов. Ответ должен не только содержать верную информацию, но и сам по себе быть грамотным во всех отношениях. Это относится ко всем участникам (я и себя не исключаю).Иногда можно видеть ответы, которые неряшливы и небрежны, без начала и без конца. Качество, как я считаю,  должно быть не на последнем месте.

Comment: Sharon, я рад, спасибо за поддержку!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Редактирование:

*Причём, следует отметить, логическое ударение **хотя и падает** на одну часть (правда, видоизмененную, что и обусловливает изменение смысла), **но** несёт различный смысл в обоих случаях.*

**Примечание.** Редактирую только грамматику (не стиль и не семантику, они тоже нуждаются в редактировании).

Пояснение

1) Запятая перед ***хотя*** не нужна, так как союз ХОТЯ И...НО относится **к однородным членам:** ударение хотя и падает, но несет.

Вряд ли здесь можно говорить **о неполном предложении** (это именно однородные сказуемые). Сравним: *Он хотя и маленький, но вполне хороший.*

2) **О простом и двойном союзе**

Эти союзы разные по значению, **хотя** иногда заменяют друг друга: **ХОТЯ**  — противительный союз, **ХОТЯ...НО, ХОТЯ И...НО** — противительно-уступительные союзы.

Я полагаю, что при наличии  И это всегда противительно-уступительный союз: ХОТЯ И...НО.

Comment: Замечательно, что Вы поддержали моё мнение! Спасибо! А мне правильно кажется, что можно выбрать вместо "но" и "однако" (хотя и... однако)? И ещё интересно: Вы считаете, что "хотя" предпочтительнее "хоть"? А почему? "Хоть" Вы вообще допускаете возможным?

Comment: Союзы НО и ОДНАКО относятся к  противительным союзам, по значению они синонимы и могут заменять друг друга. Поэтому двойной союз ХОТЯ И...ОДНАКО возможен. Что касается "хоть", то этот вариант употребляется, и в словарях он указан, но мне он кажется разговорным, не книжным.

Answer (score 1):

Это право автора - использовать простой союз хоть/хотя или двойной хоть...но, у него простой - всё верно, ошибки нет.

*Причём, следует отметить, логическое ударение, хоть и падает на одну часть (правда, видоизмененную, что и обусловливает изменение смысла), несёт различный смысл в обоих случаях.*

И запятая на месте. Если придаточное предложение, вводную и вставную конструкции убрать, остаётся: *Причём логическое ударение несёт различный смысл в обоих случаях*. Придаточное неполное с пропуском подлежащего **оно** - хоть и падает на одну часть (правда, видоизмененную, ...).

Comment: А почему при перестановке запятая не нужна, а так становится нужна?